# Encode 1920x1080 into edid format

Tags: linux, resolution, hexadecimal, edid

The EDID format specifies

"byte 38: X resolution, divided by 8, less 31 (256–2288 pixels, value 00 is reserved and should not be used)

byte 39: X:Y pixel ratio: 00=16:10; 01=4:3; 10=5:4; 11=16:9."

byte 39 makes sense (I should set it to 11), but when should I make the conversion to hex in the first byte encoding?

(((hex)1920)/8))-31
or
(hex)((1920/8)-31)

where the (hex) is a change to hex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal does not change the value, only the format in which the number is written.

```
(((hex)780/(dec)8))-(dec)31
```

and

```
(((dec)1920/(dec)8))-(dec)31
```

are equivalent, and both evaluate to `0xD1` (hex) or `209` (decimal).

It is actually byte 39 which is ambiguous in your question, because you did not specify whether `16:9` is 11 in decimal or hex (though I suspect it's 11 in hex)